# Rocketmq No topic route info in name server for the topic

Tags: rocketmq

I have a DLedger cluster composed of three machines, such as SA00, SA01, SA02;
[image]

Now I create a topic ops06 and import some data;

```
./bin/mqadmin checkMsgSendRT -n xx.xxx.1.251:9876 -s 2 -t ops06 -a 1000
```

and I turn off the host specified by topicRoute;
[image]

[image]

use ./bin/mqadmin topicRoute to view this topic, it will report "No topic route info in name server for the topic" error;
[image]

then The topic does not exist in ./bin/mqadmin topicList;
[image]

is there a solution to this problem?

The broker configuration is as follows:

```
brokerClusterName=RaftClusterSA
brokerName=RaftNodeSA02
listenPort=30911
brokerIP1=xx.xx.1.251
namesrvAddr=xx.xx.1.249:9876;xx.xx.1.250:9876;xx.xx.1.251:9876
enableDLegerCommitLog=true
dLegerGroup=RaftNodesSA
dLegerPeers=n0-xx.xx.1.249:40911;n1-xx.xx.1.250:40911;n2-xx.xx.1.251:40911
## must be unique
dLegerSelfId=n2
sendMessageThreadPoolNums=16
```

I guess the master SA01 node has not synchronized the ops06 data of SA00. How should this be solved?

Looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brokerName needs to be configured the same to form a master/slave cluster, and the data will be synchronized;
When the brokerName name is different, it is equivalent to multiple brokers, and the topic data will be distributed in different brokers, and it is possible that the broker does not save the data。